# Como rodar um script do R pela linha de comando do WIndows?

Tags: r, batch, cmd, rscript

Tenho um arquivo teste.R na pasta: C:\Users\Documents\R
E já adicionei o R no PATH do windows: C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.2\bin

Quando no cmd tento o comando `R CMD teste.R` o Windows não sabe qual programa usar para abrir o arquivo. 
Se eu usar o comando `R teste.R` 
Aparece a seguinte mensagem: ARGUMENTO ´teste.R **ignorado**
E é iniciado o R no cmd. 
Após iniciado o R se eu digitar `source("teste.R")` o windows roda o script, mas queria evitar essa etapa de iniciar o R no CMD.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode usar o argumento `BATCH` do `R CMD` ou o `Rscript`:

```
R CMD BATCH teste.R
```

ou

```
Rscript teste.R
```

Comment: no linux a saída de `R CMD BATCH teste.R` é o arquivo `teste.Rout`. Já a saída de `Rscript teste.R` vai para o terminal. Esse é o mesmo comportamento no windows?

Comment: Isso, a mesma coisa!